# Yum repo autorefresh setting

Tags: yum, rhel7, nexus

Following [Sonatype's documentation for Nexus 2 and Yum repositories](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/RPM+Packages+and+YUM+Repositories) for many years, I've faithfully added:

```
autorefresh=1
```

to my Yum repos.  However, looking at the man page for yum.conf on RHEL 7, 6 and 5(!), I don't see any reference to that setting.  Is it fictional?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf), yes. There's no mention of an "autorefresh" option for yum repos.

Answer (score 2):

Its a SuSE Zypper thing it seems, not Yum's.

Though I couldn't find it in the manpage (except a command line option), its documented on Ansible at least: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/zypper_repository_module.html

Here is the manpage: https://www.unix.com/man-page/suse/8/zypper/